# ZF2 Form 'GET' method without the standard query string

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to remove those query string when submiting a form with GET method, and use the segmented route instead.

Basically when i send the form, it generates the following URL:

```
http://zend.localhost/search?itemId=&itemName=&itemType=0
```

But i want something like this:

```
http://zend.localhost/search/123/something/4
```

Comment: The only way to do this is with some ugly JS, or to redirect after submitting the form. Neither are worth the effort IMHO

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? I also think this is not a real ZF2 question. You should reconsider your tags.

Comment: I am still learning ZF2. I thought that's the purpose of the segment routes. And yes, this is a real zf2 questions, i realize i can do it using ZF2, what's the problem in asking?  
Maybe i can achieve that rewriting the htaccess rules, no?